# Move around picture inside picturebox with the mouse

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to be able to drag around a 100% zoomed picture in a picturebox: http://spunit.tk/x/dragpic1.png.

I want it to work exactly like the Windows Photo Viewer: http://spunit.tk/x/dragpic2.png.

How is this possible?

Comment: Don't use the Image property, you'll have to use the Paint event instead.  It takes a fair chunk of code.

Comment: is this winforms or wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to maintain the coordinates of that picturebox, also set its view style to full-image, without any stretching.

Then, you will need three mouse events: mouse down, mouse up and mouse move, where you can get the mouse coordinates and capture or release mouse to translate the picture box according to mouse delta translation.

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates of that picturebox"? Its Top and Left and Size shall allays be the same. And now when zoomed like this its SizeMode is set to Zoom, which seems to work correctly.

But about the events, it seems to me that that would be right. I've messed around with that, but cannot get how to really do it...

Comment: I mean you should change Top and Left of the picturebox to simulate the image moving around.

Comment: Oh... So when picture is moved down 1 px, Top = -1 and Height = 1 px. You mean like that?

Comment: When the image is need to be moved down from [0; 0] to [0; 1], the picture box' `Left` property remains `0`, and its `Top` property becomes `1`.